# Реверсивный ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-orm

Могут ли два объекта с ManyToManyField использовать одну промежуточную таблицу?

```
class ObjectOne(models.Model):
    bars = ManyToManyField('ObjectTwo', db_table=object_one_to_object_two)

class ObjectTwo(models.Model):
    bars = ManyToManyField(ObjectOne , db_table=object_one_to_object_two)
```

При создании файла миграции выходит примерно такая ошибка.
(fields.E340) The field's intermediary table 'objects_one' clashes with the table name of 'object_two'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что бы использовать промежуточную таблицу для двух моделей, вам необходима создать для этой таблицы модель, а потом передать ее в параметре through у ManyToManyField

Пример из [документации django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/)

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

Если же в промежуточной модели нет дополнительных полей то вам достаточно будет такого варианта:

```
class ObjectOne(models.Model):
    bars = ManyToManyField('ObjectTwo')

class ObjectTwo(models.Model):
    ....
```

Django автоматически создаст таблицу которая свяжет две эти модели